# Why is the jquery loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know I sound like an idiot right now but I cant find why I never get the number 0 in the loop.

**http://jsfiddle.net/7uSAN/5/**

```
var timer = 0;

setInterval(function() {
      if (timer == 1)
      {
          var timer = 0;
          $("#box").html(timer);
      }
      else
      {
          var timer = 1;
          $("#box").html(timer);
      }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: the use of `var` in the if and else statements introduces a new local variable and assignments do not affect the outer-scoped variable.  Simply remove `var` in the if/else clauses.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/epEZiwA/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the var statement to toggle between those conditions. The var inside those conditions creates a local `var timer`.

Removing the `var` would fix the issue as it would be updating the `timer` var that is declared outside.

```
var timer = 0;

setInterval(function() {
      if (timer == 1)
      {
          timer = 0;
          $("#box").html(timer);
      }
      else
      {
          timer = 1;
          $("#box").html(timer);
      }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

you are declaring new `timer` variable for both if blocks. Remove `var`

```
var timer = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  if (timer == 1)
  {
      timer = 0;
      $("#box").html(timer);
  }
  else
  {
      timer = 1;
      $("#box").html(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```